# How to use Socket.io with the MEAN stack?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, socket.io, mean-stack

So I can't seem to find a way to use Socket.io and MEAN together.  I can get it running in the latest version without errors with:

```
var server = app.listen(config.port, config.hostname);
io = io.listen(server);
```

But io, socket, doesn't have scope anywhere inside of Angular.  I'm kind of new to all of this, so this might be a massive oversight on my part, but any insight to how I can overcome this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at btford/angular-socket-io on github
Is an angular wrapper for client side socket.io.

Answer (score 0):

[Express.IO](http://express-io.org/) is built for using the express framework in the MEAN stack along with Socket.IO

Answer (score 0):

I've just responded to another SO post ([Mean.io framwork with socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526374/mean-io-framwork-with-socket-io)) for the same issue. Hope it helps.

**Note:** I'm using mean.io v0.5.26 and socket.io v1.1.0.